# Token Range Offset Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We are planning to add a new datacenter to our cluster. We currently have initial_token mentioned in the YAML file for each node. When we add the new datacenter, could we have the same set of token ranges mentioned for the nodes in new datacenter. What impact would it have if we did not offset the token ranges in new datacenter.

```
 DC1 : Node-1 : 0
       Node-2 : 25
       Node-3 : 50
       Node-4 : 75 

 DC2 : Node-1 : 0
       Node-2 : 25
       Node-3 : 50
       Node-4 : 75
```

Answer (score 1):

No two nodes can share the same token even if they are in different datacenters.   You should try to offset your nodes in a different DC by some value with regards to their counterparts (maybe 100 or so) to accommodate replacing nodes.  Usually when you replace a node you fire up a new one with the token of the one you are replacing+1.

This is in older C* 1.1 documentation, but the strategy is explained [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/1.1/docs/initialize/token_generation.html):

> When adding nodes to a cluster, you must avoid token collisions. You can do this by offsetting the token values, which allows room for the new nodes.
>   The following graphic shows an example using an offset of +100:
>
> [image: Datacenter Tokens]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to consider vnodes for your cluster, here is a good [article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2) for vnodes and heterogenous hardware